# Error while selection in C#

Tags: c#

I want to display data from Database with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TestDatabase
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
            AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\DOT NET\Projects\
            TestDatabase\TestDatabase\Contact.mdf;
            Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
            string query = "select * from Stu";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name: " + dr["Name"]);
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run my code the below exception is occurred.

```
{"An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\\Users\\Mani\\Desktop\\DOT NET\\Projects\\\r\n  TestDatabase\\TestDatabase\\Contact.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."}
```

Please help!

Comment: Your answer is right there in the exception description.

Comment: Just correct the database path in your verbatim string

Answer (score 9):

You have a new line in the middle of your string, in the middle of the file path, and it cannot find the file. Put your connection string all on one line and it should fix the issue.

So:

```
string cs = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\DOT NET\Projects\TestDatabase\TestDatabase\Contact.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
```

or

```
string cs = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;"+
        "AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\DOT NET\Projects\"+
        "TestDatabase\TestDatabase\Contact.mdf;"+
        "Integrated Security=True";
```